# Guice-like solution from Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, guice

Here is a typical Guice "bindings" which are configured without XML:

**ServeModule.java**

```
public class ServeModule extends ServletModule {
    public ServeModule() {
    }
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        filter("/*").through(ShiroFilter.class);
        serve(userBaseUrl + "/ajaxLogin").with(LoginServlet.class);
    }

}
```

**ServeLogic.java**

```
public class ServeLogic extends AbstractModule {
    public ServeLogic() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(IOAuthProviderInfo.class).to(FacebookAuth.class);
        bind(CreateDoc.class).toInstance(createDoc());
        bind(ShiroFilter.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    }
}
```

What's appealing to this is that the app only needs to define the `com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter` in the web.xml and every servlet that needs to be hosted are configured all in java.

My question would be, is there anything like this with Spring Framework?

That is, if I use the Spring Framework how can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi xybrek, I did not get your question. Could you write a little more what's your intend? What is unclear? What means "is there *anything like this* with spring?

Comment: @MilanBaran A way to bind "servlets" through Java not with XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible to configure servlets without xml in Spring since the version 3.1.
Look at the following [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html).

You have to implements `WebApplicationInitializer` like this (*example from the documentation*):

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
      // Create the 'root' Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
        new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

      // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
      container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

      // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext =
        new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
        container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actaully, you have bound your servlets and filters trough java. The `serve(urls...)` method bind your servlet to specific urls and `filter(urls..)` method bind your filter to specific urls.

All you need to do via wmb.xml (the xml way) is bind `GuiceFilter` ([link](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets)) and `ContextListener` ([link](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule)). Then you need to bootstrap your Guice injector by implementing `GuiceServletContextListener.getInjector` method. There you will install your `ServeModule` and `ServeLogic`. It will look like this:

```
public class MyGuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {

  @Override
  protected Injector getInjector() {
    return Guice.createInjector(new ServeModule(), new ServeLogic());
  }
}
```

**web.xml**:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.MyGuiceServletConfig</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Comment: Actually my question is if there is a way to do Guice-like servlet mapping using the Spring Framework?

Comment: Naah, Guice should be able to bind Spring beans servlet included, but I have never try it. With that configuration xml. There is no such a thing in Guice. You have to realize Guice is a lightweight DI framework not a EE stack. 

So, I would suggest you, create a xml configuration file which will serve your needs, then create a module and reuse it everywhere you go. It is not so much work.

Comment: I'm not trying to combine Guice and Spring, actually what I was looking for is a similar "tech", that is, I want to use Spring instead of Guice, but I want to have a similar Java-based servet mapping using the Spring Framework and not Guice